# Intel 8052 (and friends) minimum set up

Tags: microcontroller, ftdi, intel

I recently got a batch of old microcontrollers (8052 and Z8671) and I just want to get a minimum working set up for them.

Since these microcontrollers already have most everything baked into them (BASIC, RAM, ROM, Serial Ports), it seems like it'd be a simple matter of plugging them in to an FTDI chip and going about myself.

Looking at the Intel 8052 datasheet, it seems like all I need is a power source, crystal oscillator, and a serial port. Since the FTDI FT232RL is a very common and readily accessible chip, I'm using that for both power and serial I/O.

Here is what I'm using as a schematic[image: 8052 Schematic].

With all that in place, and trying to use both minicom and picocom, I get no response from the chip at all.

What is it that I'm missing? I've tried using a similar set up for the Z8671 and haven't gotten a response as well.

For reference, here is the pinout of the 8052 [image: 8052 Pinout]

Comment: Many older 8051 variants predate Flash program memory and thus have EPROM or OTP program memory, or are ROMless, requiring an external program memory chip to run.  Is there a reason you don't go with a more modern controller?

Comment: Do you think this would be the case in a (c)1980 8052AH?

Comment: A standard Intel 8052 does not have BASIC preloaded. What part do you actually have?

Comment: And the datasheet says.....?

Comment: @SteveG you're right...I swear I read it having that. I'll swap it out for the Z8671, test, alter the question.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel there  is no reason to go with it other than for fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since these microcontrollers already have most everything baked into them (BASIC, RAM, ROM, Serial Ports)

What makes you think that these microcontrollers have BASIC built in?

There was one somewhat rare version of the 8052 that had a BASIC interpreter built in. If you have one of these, it will be clearly marked as a "P8052AH-BASIC", like this one:

[image: P8052AH-BASIC]

These parts were neither standard nor common. The ROM in most other 8052s will contain an application-specific program that's unlikely to be useful to you.

Comment: That's the problem right here. 8052AH vs 8052AH-BASIC. I'll accept it and it sounds like a different post would be needed for the Zilog chip.

Answer (score 4):

Intel 8052 has factory programmed mask ROM whose contents cannot be changed. Since you didn't order these chips from the factory, you don't know what firmware is inside.

**You will need at the minimum 3 components to be able to run software on this IC**: The 8051 controller, an EEPROM chip such as 27C256 and a 8-bit address latch such as 74HC573.

Connect EA low to make the controller run code from external ROM, PSEN to the EEPROM chip select, ALE to the 74HC573 latch enable, 74HC573 inputs to P0, 74HC573 outputs to the EEPROM's A0..A7, EEPROM's A8..An to P2 and EEPROM D0..D7 to P0 and you're good to go.

Use any ancient prommer to write your firmware into the eeprom and enjoy the classic 1980's hardcore program execution feelings!

Answer (score 1):

The capacitors on the crystal should be 15 - 20 pF, not the 100 nF you show.

You also need a 100 nF (0.1 uF) bypass capacitor between the Vcc and Ground pins of the processor, as close to the  chip pins as practical.  A 47uF or so electrolytic capacitor between Vcc and Ground would also be a good idea.

Comment: Is that because the oscillation is too fast for the capacitors to drain?

Comment: The typical crystal oscillator circuit requires low-value load capacitors for proper operation.